# returning back to calling fragment where start activity is called

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have looked some example but none are working for me.
From MainActivity I call a fragment with a string. The fragment uses that string and populates list view.

When user clicks on a list entry, I need to open another activity say ShowData.java which will show some details of that entry. Once user returns, I should come back to the same fragment which shows the list populated for the string earlier.

How can I achieve this could any body provide a sample code?

My MainActivity contains list of strings. For first run it calls Fragment with first string which is displayed as default when application open.
When user selects another string, the fragment is reloaded with the data associated with the string chosen by user.

so when current fragment view is with string3, and new activity opens (by clicking list entry), going back is not showing data with string3 rather it shows data with string1. That means from MainActivity it is being called with first string.

How make this work?

Comment: Can you show us some code please? this looks like a simple fragment navigation using for example `getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();`

Comment: In Fragmnet:    public void showDataContent(String info, String details) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), showDataActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("INFO", info);
        intent.putExtra("DETAILS", details);
        intent.putExtra("TITLE", title);
        intent.putExtra("SHOWLOCATION", showLocation);
        ShowListFragment.this.startActivityForResult(intent, MyGlobals.AI_DATA_SHOWN);
    }

Comment: In Main activity:    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if(requestCode == MyGlobals.AI_DATA_SHOWN){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String title = data.getStringExtra("TITLE");
                updateShowListFragment(title);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: updateShowListFragment() does:  fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: Unable to write everything as single comments here. shows restricted to 550 characters while writing comments.

Comment: read some where that only MainActivity onActivityResult only called so I put code in MainActivity.java which is main. But debugger is hitting while returning from the activity showDataActivity(). in showDataActivity() onStop() i created intent and put some data and called finish().